# disable mod_security for a bridge.php script

Tags: php, regex, apache, mod-security

I want to use a regex pattern to disable `mod_security` of Apache for 2 scripts: `bridge.php` and `mobile-bridge.php`.

I think I can do it in a file named `mod_security_whitelist.conf` inside the configuration folder `/etc/httpd/httpd/conf.d`:

[ Please correct me if I am wrong somewhere ]

```
<IfModule mod_security2.c>
    # ModSecurity disabled for bridge.php and mobile-bridge.php scripts
    <DirectoryMatch "/home/websitename/public_html">
       <Files "([a-z],-)*bridge\.php$">
          SecRuleEngine Off
        </Files>
     </DirectoryMatch>
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the files are in a specific location—such as right at the first path of the URL—then use something like [`LocationMatch`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#locationmatch):

```
<IfModule mod_security2.c>
  <LocationMatch /(mobile-bridge.php|bridge.php)>
    SecRuleEngine Off
  </LocationMatch>
</IfModule>
```

But there is a nice equivalent of that for files called [`FilesMatch`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#filesmatch) that should work as well:

```
<IfModule mod_security2.c>
  <FilesMatch (mobile-bridge.php|bridge.php)>
    SecRuleEngine Off
  </FilesMatch >
</IfModule>
```

Or perhaps it would work like this:

```
<IfModule mod_security2.c>
  <FilesMatch "([a-z],-)*bridge\.php$">
    SecRuleEngine Off
  </FilesMatch >
</IfModule>
```